# C# PrintDocument Not working on all printers

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'm seeing inconsistent results when printing directly to printers. My application is taking configuration data about page sizes and margins, and prints a bitmap file. On a lot of printers it works perfectly but on some, the output is just completely different if I print the same image through GIMP for example.

My code:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += (senderp, args) =>
{
    Image i = ConvertToBitmap();

    args.Graphics.DrawImage(i, Convert.ToInt32(_leftMargin / 0.254), Convert.ToInt32(_topMargin / 0.254), Convert.ToInt32(_widthOfPrintMedia / 0.254), Convert.ToInt32(_lengthOfPrintMedia / 0.254));
};

pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
Debug.WriteLine(_printerName);
Debug.WriteLine(_foolPrinterLength);
Debug.WriteLine(_foolPrinterWidth);
Debug.WriteLine(_leftMargin);
Debug.WriteLine(_topMargin);
Debug.WriteLine(_widthOfPrintMedia);
Debug.WriteLine(_lengthOfPrintMedia);
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = _printerName;
pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", Convert.ToInt32(_foolPrinterWidth / 0.254), Convert.ToInt32(_foolPrinterLength / 0.254));
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", Convert.ToInt32(_foolPrinterWidth / 0.254), Convert.ToInt32(_foolPrinterLength / 0.254));
pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
pd.Print();
```

As I said, it works perfectly on most printers, but some just wont play ball. This is the .prn file when using a Citizen CL-E321 printer from my application (I am specifying the width of 30mm):

```
<xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='30.0 mm'></xpml>G0
n
M0500
O0214
V0
t1
Kf0070
SE
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='30.0 mm'></xpml>L
D11
PE
pK
SK
Q0001
E
<xpml></page></xpml>SE
<xpml><end/></xpml>
```

And this is the exact same image printed from BarTender:

```
<xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='30.0 mm'></xpml>G0
n
M0500
O0214
V0
t1
Kf0070
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='40.0 mm'></xpml>ICYgfx0
 ÿ  (

 h ÌãŽ8ãŽ8ãŽ8ãŽ8ãÌqÇqÇqÇqÇŒÿÌAAAAAÌ¾ûï¾ûï¾ûï¾ûï¾ÌqÇqÇqÇqÇÌãŽ8ãŽ8ãŽ8ãŽ8ãÌqÇqÇqÇqÇÌã€ ãˆ £Ž8ãŽ8ãÆ þ 7ÿ@Ä @ Æ 
( 
(˜Æõ×Áõ×hÀÆ QDQEÆ®»É®ºìÀÀÀ0Æ
Š(Š(¢ÀÆùuÖûu×]ÿÁ÷ïÿÀÆ QF QEÀÆ®¸®ºïÁ®ÀâÀòÅŸüà ?ÿÌŠ(Š(¢ ¢Š" Ì
u×
u×]p]uÚ Ãð àÁ8ÀãÌQCQEqÇQGÌ®°®ºë€ ë®¸ ÌÂŠ ðŠ(¢‡0¢Š(sÌ]u×
u×]tß]u×LÀ€ÀÀ Á”QÈQE@QE Ì‹®Çý®ºë³ÿk®ºßÂ@ À ÌBŠ Š(¢€ bŠ( Ì
uÀu×]p 
u×\ÀÀÌQ@QEP QEÌ®€®ºë  ®ºïÂ` ÀÌbŠ Š(¢„ Š(¢Ç
uÀu×]pÂu×]ÀÌ”QüQEQÿþQEÌk®ð®ºë¯€
®ºëÀÌ"Š Š(¢Š Š(¢ÌÝuÐ
u×]u°íu×]Á ÀÁ”QÈQEQQDÌk®ø?®ºë®ûï®»ëÌ"Š Š(¢Š(¢Š(ÌÝuÐýu×]u×]u×ýÀÁÌQ@QEQEQ Ì®€k®ºë®ºë®ÀÂ` Á`Ì‚Š&"Š(¢Š(¢Š/Ìýuñ]u×]u×]uð
Á0 ÌQOQEQEQÿüÊk®€k®ºë®ºï¤À€ÀÊbŠ ¢Š(¢Š(£€ÊuÏ]u×]u×\ÿÀ ÊQQEQD€Éë®÷ë®ºë®»áÉ"Š ¢Š(¢Š(€ÉÝuß]u×]u×@ÈQQEQDÉë®úë®ºë®»ÀÃ ‚ÌâŠ8¢Š(¢Š(÷ß}÷Èuƒ]u×]uÐÇQQEQÇë®ºë®ºë®„ÿÀÈ"Š ¢Š(¢Š&ÈÝu¿]u×]ußƒÿÈQ…QEQ@Èk®ë®ºë®€Â€  À?ƒÿÇ¢Š(¢Š(¢ŠÈ]u×]u×]uðÀÄãŽ8âÌQÅQEQÇqÇÇk®ë®ºë®Ç"Š¢Š(¢ŠÈ]t‡]u×]u€Á 
ÈQ…QEQ€Çk®ë®ºë®ÀÇ"Š¢Š(¢ŠÀÌ]uÇ]u×]tÃ0ÃÅ<óÏ<ðÇQQEQÈë®úë®ºë®€ÀÂ€  À‚ÿÀþÇbŠ¢Š(¢ŠÀÇuÇ]u×]tÇ”QQEQƒÿÀüÈk®úë®ºë¯€ÀÈ"Š(¢Š(¢‰€ÀÇ]u×]u×]vÀ
ÇQDQE@Ço®»ë®ºë¾ÀÀÇŠ(¢Š(¢ˆÁÌ]u×]u×]tAýÃ¸ Åï¾ûçÇQ@QE`Ç®¸®ºë€ÁïÀâÀ`Å8ãŽ ÌŠ(Š(¢‰Çp¢Ç
u×Íu×]pÂ×]ÇüQE<AEÿÂñEÆ®º >ºèÂºëÀ@ÀÆŠ(@
( Â
(¢Æþu×u×_ÿÃþu×]ÀÀÅQEQEÂQEÆ®ºï®ºøÃ®ºïÀÆ 
(¢Š(ÃŠ( Æu×]u×@Ãýu×]Á€    ÀÆ EQD€ÃQD Ì >ºë®º@ ë®»àÁ@ÃqÀÀÌãŽ(¢Š(ãŽ8¢Š(ãÅ ×]uÐÄ]uÐ Á ÀÌ0QB0…QCÌóÎúë®»óÏºë®¼óÂ Ã(¢Š(Â(¢ŠÌ ×]u×À×]uÀ Á ÃQDÂE@È:ë®»ý~ºë¾Ç¢Š(¢Š(¢È]u×]u×]`ÂóÏ<ÂO<óÌ0ÃQEQE0ÃÆ®ºë®ºè‚ÿÆâŠ(¢Š(£‚ÿÆu×]u×\Ìa†`QQE†aÌžyçœ úë®ºyçžÀ Ã¢Š(Ã]uÐÀÃpÀÀÀŒÿ
L
D11
A2
1Y1100000310000gfx0
Q0001
E
<xpml></page></xpml>xCGgfx0
zC
<xpml><end/></xpml>
```

It looks like the image part is just not being written to the printer to me. My issue is that it is inconsistent. It will work fine with most printers but not quite all of them. I set the 'DefaultPageSettings' in both place above as I read elsewhere that someone had some success with this but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I'm not sure what else to try. I have tried multiple different images all with the same result. I have run this on 9 different printers and 7 of them work perfectly. I can't help but think I'm missing something because if BarTender works ok, then it can't be a printer issue.

Any guidance would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a PS or PCL driver?  You may have the wrong type driver installed.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure. I'm using the default Seagull driver. Is there a way I can find out?

Comment: Go into Control Panel and select Devices and Printers.  If you click on the printer at the bottom of the view will show the info.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, but I only have 3 things listed when I do that: Model, Category and Status and nowhere seems to say.

Comment: My Model says "RICHO PCL6 Universal Driver V4.23". Did you right click printer and check the properties?  We had lots of issues in the past so our MIS people got smart and added the driver name to the Model.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately not. It only has the name and model of the printer and is the same for all printers. I've been through every option I can find as well and I just can't find anywhere that references what kind of driver it is.

Comment: May be with Regedit : https://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-registry-key-printer-computer-57663.html

Comment: In the past, our MIS dept setup two print queues for each printer. Some applications worked better with PCL and others with PS.  Then let user select the queue.  I had both queues installed on my PC.  If you are using a remote server for spooler the driver is probably installed on the remote machine.

Comment: @jdweng There is a bundle of information in there but none that give me any clues at all. I even went through all the other printers (the ones that work ok) and none of those have that sort of information either.

Comment: Is print queue on local machine or remote machine?  I think you need to check registry of machine where queue is located.  As I said our MIS learned that putting type type of queue in name was real useful.  Maybe installed both PS and PCL as new queues and make sure you download latest drivers from manufacturer.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, the print queue is on the local machine. The application runs on computers in a factory environment with printers plugged in directly. There are no remote machines in play at all. I'll try and contact the manufacturer to see if there are any alternative drivers.